# Curve to mesh converting

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices

I have a question about converting a curve to a mesh. Is there any way to keep the number of vertices of the curve when converting to a mesh? I would like to keep the same number of vertices to be able to use the *Bridge Edge Loop* tool.

[image]
[image]

Comment: in most cases (like yours what you showed us here) this makes no sense at all because you would loose all shape informations (it would just be a circle thing). A vertex of a mesh has no information of any "shape" beyond his point itself, what a vertex of a curve has by his handle points.

Comment: You can however reduce the number of vertices produced when converting to a mesh on the Curve Properties tab by reducing the 'Resolution U' setting under Active Spline before you do the conversion. As Chris says this will reduce the smoothness somewhat but you can CTRL-Z Undo and try again until  you get a reasonable result.

Comment: Just to clarify, the dots in the first image are curve control points. Each control point has handles that define the curvature of the curve. The dots in the second image are vertices. You need a lot more of them to define the same curved shape. You cannot convert control points to vertices 1:1.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Is there any way to construct that geometry using shape, not curve? @JohnEason

Comment: Thank you for your help @Chris

Comment: Thank you for your help @Blunder

Comment: @Jiji It's not clear from your question what you want to use the Bridge Edge Loops tool for. With your current mesh you can only select All and then F to fill to produce a flat plane. There would be nothing for the bridge tool to work with.

Comment: Hi @JohnEason, What I am trying to do is to loft this shape and another circle to create another shape, using bridge edge tool, but seems like this does not work.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7tn9kkfaioh3ty/Screen%20Shot%202022-10-13%20at%2011.01.15%20AM.png?dl=0
I want to create this leaf shape, by lofting the two edges together. But When I convert that spline to mesh, it added too many vertices.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4e6mnp9uehv92j/Screen%20Shot%202022-10-13%20at%2010.58.59%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: A bit difficult to see from those images and I still don't understand why you want to use Bridge Edge loops, but if I understand what you're trying to do I'd suggest converting to a mesh, selecting All the vertices in Edit mode then CTRL-F > Grid Fill. Select a vertex in the centre of the grid and then use proportional editing to raise (or lower) the centre.

Comment: @JohnEason : yes! The proportional editing did the work! Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help. Now added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your shape with curves. if you don't want too many vertices in the mesh you can change the number created for each spline via <kbd>Curve Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Geometry</kbd> > <kbd>Active Spline</kbd> > <kbd>Resolution U</kbd>. (Default is 12. I've set it to 6 for this case.)
[image]

In <kbd>Object Mode</kbd> convert to a mesh using <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Convert</kbd> > <kbd>Mesh</kbd> then in <kbd>Edit Mode</kbd> select All and <kbd>Face</kbd> > <kbd>Grid Fill</kbd>

[image]

Turn on <kbd>Proportional Editing</kbd> with the icon or by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>

[image]

Then drag the centre vertex up or down to produce the required shape.
[image]

Comment: OMG , this is the best! I think this is exactly what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. You should be able to mark my answer as accepted to give it a green tick and show that it worked for you. - https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour